# Is -moz-box-shadow property still supported in firefox?

Tags: css, firefox, css-selectors

Im not able to use the hack **-moz-box-shadow**.Im using **windows 64 bit** laptop.Is it got **deprecated** or not supported anymore.

Thanks,
Balaji

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`-moz-box-shadow` is for support Firefox 3.5 or less. We are in Firefox 40. Use `box-shadow` standard.

https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/box-shadow

### EDIT:

I don't say that's removed. I said that is for support old browsers.

Comment: The document you link to says that support was removed after Firefox 13, not 3.5

Comment: Thanks for you replies Marcos and Quentin, I want to have different behaviours for firefox and ie, then can I have box shadow hack for ie then, I tried with -ms-box-shadow, but not working

Comment: @balaji if you need different behaviours depending on your browser, you must to detect it with a tool like Modernizr. It allows to detect capabilities or browser and versions to make the tricks you need.

Comment: oh so, that is the only alternative

Comment: prefixes are not hacks. if you use Modernizr or Conditionizr you can make something like this in your css: `.firefox .shadow { box-shadow: 1px 1px 2px red; } .ie .shadow { box-shadow : 2px 2px 4px blue; }`. By this way you can add different behaviours in different browsers

Answer (score 4):

The `-moz-` prefix is no longer required as `box-shadow` itself is now widely supported and has been for a while.

The last time the `-moz-` prefix was required was back in version 3.6. It was finally removed from use in version 13. The current latest version of FireFox is 40.

The last time the `-webkit-` was needed was back in version 9. The current latest version of Chrome is 44.

You can view the browser support here: [CanIUse](http://caniuse.com/#search=box-shadow)

Comment: Thanks for your answer Stewart

Comment: A bit of perspective - the first version to support it unprefixed, 4, was released in 2011, and the first version to drop the prefix, 13, was released in 2012. It has been three years since the prefixed version was dropped.

Comment: @Stewartside: One word: enterprise.

Comment: Yeah, Enterprises and Public Administrations. @BoltClock you're right

Answer (score 1):

Yes! I think it was removed : 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-shadow

Comment: Thanks for your answer :)